# How do you add a swagger comment to the "Request and Response Model"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

You can add a comment on the methods like the example below but what about adding comments to the request and response model?

```
/// <summary>
/// my summary
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// remark goes here.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="somepara">Required parameter: Example: </param>
/// <return>Returns comment</return>
/// <response code="200">Ok</response>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes just like Dimitar said, you can add comments to the responses with **SwaggerResponse**, the request is a bit different, just like you added xml comments to your action you should add to the parameters, here is an example:

```
using Swagger.Net.Annotations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Results;

namespace Swagger_Test.Controllers
{
    public class IHttpActionResultController : ApiController
    {

        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "List of customers", typeof(IEnumerable<int>))]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, Type = typeof(NotFoundResult))]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(MyData data)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>My super duper data</summary>
    public class MyData
    {
        /// <summary>The unique identifier</summary>
        public int id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Everyone needs a name</summary>
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in swagger that will look like:
[image]

Comment: Here is a live example:
http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=IHttpActionResult#/IHttpActionResult/IHttpActionResult_Post

Comment: And here is the code behind that:
https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/eb89ab65a3e735f022104c153f2f7af21bc8bf48/Swagger_Test/Controllers/IHttpActionResultController.cs

Comment: now this is interesting I added /// <summary>The unique identifier</summary> ... just like in the shown example but the description is not displayed in swagger doc, my models are in a separate project (does it matter?)

Comment: ...strange, but you can see it in my example, Right?   _ _ _      It must be something in your swashbuckle configuration, make sure you enable the IncludeXmlComments

Comment: I tried adding <summary> to the models inside the same project. (yes include xml comments is enabled already, I can see comments in the method just fine)

Comment: ASP.NET Core with Swashbuckle - 6.0.0-beta902

Comment: Can you create a GitHub project that reproduces your issue?  I can help you troubleshoot that way...  it could be a bug in that version of Swashbuckle.Core

Comment: Interesting, I created a new web api, and the swagger description works! (the same configuration was used in my original app but description never works! I did a clean /rebuild still doesnt work)

Comment: Its a bug!? if you have external models swagger will not generate the model description. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203601/swagger-no-comment-for-external-models-is-this-a-bug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149659/discussion-between-heldersepu-and-001).

Answer (score 18):

I'm using .net core 3.0, so in addition to @Helder's response, I had to do below two more steps to make XML comments visible.

manually edit the project file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

add below to startup.cs service configuration method.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "My Good API",
                    Version = "v1",
                    Description = "Doesn't hurt to add some description."
                });

                // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
```

From the [microsoft docs for Swagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments)

> XML comments can be enabled with the following approaches:
>
> - Manually add the highlighted lines to the .csproj file:
>
> Enabling XML comments provides debug information for undocumented
> public types and members. Undocumented types and members are indicated
> by the warning message. For example, the following message indicates a
> violation of warning code 1591:

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if that's what exactly you're talking about, but you can add comments to the different responses like this

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Authorization has been denied for this request")]
```

This is attribute which you use to decorate your controller method.

Comment: Adding response comments can also be done using XML -  response code.

Answer (score 2):

For those that aren't having luck with the existing answers, make sure that the project your property class lives in has the xml documentation enabled as well.

In my case, I had a separate project for my DTOs and needed to add it in there as well. Be sure to include xml comments from that project as well with another `IncludeXmlComments` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add annotation without xml

```
    //program.cs
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.EnableAnnotations();
    });

    using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations; 

    //inside model class
    [SwaggerSchema(Description = "My super duper data")] 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //in controller
    [SwaggerOperation(Summary = "My controller")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(MyData data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Placement reference:  [SwaggerOperation(Summary="On method header", Description="On top, inside")]