# How can I add information to an endpoint in NSwag for .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nswag

Pretty much the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232175/nswag-how-do-i-add-comments), but for .NET Framework/Webforms instead of .NET Core:

**How can I add a little information to a controller endpoint, so that it is displayed in the swagger UI *in .NET Framework*?**

Just adding doc comments does not work, and the next step in the linked answer, adding

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

in the .csproj also doesn't work - there's no XML fie generated (but I suspect that it's a .NET Core setting anyway).

I found [the doc comment documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/how-to-use-the-xml-documentation-features) saying that you can create the XML file by using `csc XMLsample.cs /doc:XMLsample.xml`. HOWEVER, `csc` is called "automatically" in the C# build target, and not in my .csproj file. If there is a way to pass the `/doc` parameter to it, that would be a solution, but it feels like that might be the wrong way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on this for a whole day yesterday, but literally 10 seconds after I posted this answer I found the setting

ProjectSettings => Build => Output => XML documentation file

I turned that on and now it works.