# How to add example value to openapi.json in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In OpenAPI 3.0, there is a [Adding Examples](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/) feature. I can add some example value to the Swagger UI. I'm using ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. Is it possible add these example value to the API action and reflect these example values to the openapi.json that generated by ASP.NET Core automatically?

Comment: which library are you using for generating the swagger.json ?

Comment: One of NSwag and Swashbuckle

Comment: with swashbuckle, there are many ways you can add examples take a look at some of the links [article1](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/multiple-request-response-examples-for-swagger-ui-in-asp-net-core-864c0bdc6619) and [article 2](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/enhance-swagger-documentation-with-annotations-in-asp-net-core-d2981803e299)

Comment: @CodingMytra Can you put your suggestion to the Answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By utilizing `<example>`

```cs
public class MyRequest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Email parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>cool-service-account@my-cool-org.com</example>
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and adding this in your `Startup.cs`

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "My Good API",
                    Version = "v1",
                    Description = "Doesn't hurt to add some description."
                });

                // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
```

Bumping up [@CodingMytra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9247039/codingmytra)'s suggestion, for more options see [here](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/multiple-request-response-examples-for-swagger-ui-in-asp-net-core-864c0bdc6619) and [here](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/enhance-swagger-documentation-with-annotations-in-asp-net-core-d2981803e299)

Comment: Is this apply to both NSwag & Swashbuckle?

Comment: This seems not working on Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v6.2.3.

Comment: Adding this is required: `c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "WebApplication1.xml"));`

Comment: Both. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58633937/9420697) if you encounter issues.